# set the expiration date for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, setcookie

I ran across a small problem with deleting a cookie.

I'm in the domain **my.domain.net**

I have a cookie (not an HTTP cookie) with an expiration of 15 days.
The cookie's domain is in **my.domain.com**
and I need to delete that cookie so I'm doing the following:

document.cookie = '.ASPXAUTH=;expire=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/;domain=my.domain.net';

The thing is that it creates another cookie with the same name BUT under the domain: **.my.domain.net**
I assume that is the reason I can't delete that cookie.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a little investigation, I found the answer:
I just don't need to set the domain for that cookie i.e.:

```
document.cookie = '.ASPXAUTH=;expire=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/';
```